# Animation, delay

Tags: android, animation, delay

I would like to make an animation, I have 10 images of a ball and I want to do:

1. `Image1` visible, all the other images hidden
2. `Image2` visible all the other images hidden
3. ...
4. `Image10` visible all the other images hidden

Should I do that in one animation (how?) or should I create a java method showImage(String pathimage) which would show the image located at pathimage and hide the others? Could I put any idea of time delay with using

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { }
}
```

**EDIT, here is my code**
The problem is that run() is always called in what seems to be an infinite loop. But I don't see where is my error

GAMEACTIVITY

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
.....
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        image2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                myAsyncRunnable mar = new myAsyncRunnable(GameActivity.this);
                mar.execute(null);
                PhotoTask photoTask = new PhotoTask(camera,surfaceCamera,isPreview,holder,GameActivity.this);
                photoTask.execute(null);
                Log.w("GAMEACTIVITY","PHOTOTASK");
                return false;
            }

        });
}
```

My Async Task

```
public class myAsyncRunnable extends AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, Void> {

    GameActivity gameactivity;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        pull();
        return null;
    }

public myAsyncRunnable(GameActivity gameactivity) {
    super();
    this.gameactivity = gameactivity;
}


    public void pull() {

        final ImageView image3 = (ImageView) gameactivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        final int drawables[] = new int[] {R.drawable.pull2,R.drawable.pull3,R.drawable.pull4,R.drawable.pull5,R.drawable.pull6,R.drawable.pull7};
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i=0;i<drawables.length;i++) {
                    image3.setImageResource(drawables[i]);
                    gameactivity.handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
                    Log.w("asyncrunnable","run"+i);
                }

            }

        };
        gameactivity.handler.post(runnable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create 10 ImageViews to do such animation.

Only one ImageView should suffice! Use a handler to update the Image using any flavor of `setImage` every x milliseconds or so.

Initialize the images in an array and the current image in an integer :

```
int drawables[] = new int[] {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, ...};
int mCurrent = 0;
```

Then initialize your updater:

```
 Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
                 if(mCurrent>=drawables.length)mCurrent=0;
                 imageView.setImageResource(drawables[mCurrent]);
                 mHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000); //every 3 seconds
    }
};
```

Finally when you want to start, just post the runnable:

```
mHandler.post(runnable);
```

---

Your code is wrong:

Try this pull function (although i do not really approve the whole code style but no time to fix that)

```
public void pull() {

    final ImageView image3 = (ImageView) gameactivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    final int drawables[] = new int[] {R.drawable.pull2,R.drawable.pull3,R.drawable.pull4,R.drawable.pull5,R.drawable.pull6,R.drawable.pull7};
            for (int i=0;i<drawables.length;i++) {
                final int j = i;
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                image3.setImageResource(drawables[j]);

        }

    };
                gameactivity.handler.postDelayed(this, 500 * i);
                Log.w("asyncrunnable","run"+i);
            }
}
```

}

Comment: And do you know how I could possibly do a loop?
Because   image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.pathimagei) of course does not work as pathimagei is not a drawable but the string it refers to yes..

Comment: Ok thanks, now I have a problem because I think this is too slow to be executed in the main UI thread. Shall I have the runnable extending AsyncTask?

Comment: Too slow? that is the minimum work. You are only setting the image. If you want to use an asynctask, you might load the Bitmap in the background then set it in the onPostExecute. But since your images are in res/ then you wont gain that much (it should already be fast)

Comment: Or it takes too much space ? Because I have a "config thread select time out" and "Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock", the animation executes but the application won't go to the next activity

Comment: Yes, see my edit. Logcat says that run() keeps being called I don't know why

Comment: Just a modification : postDelayed(runnable,500*j) where j is a final int = i just after the for statement. It works,thanks a lot for your help Sherif!

Comment: oops yes fixed :) Actually the problem is in `image3.setImageResource(drawables[j]);` because it is inside the runnable